# ArchLinux no Arranca

Tags: linux, windows

Tengo un laptop que tiene un disco de estado sólido que ocupo para mi sistema (windows 10) y un disco duro de 1TB (que reemplace CD-ROM con enclosure interno).

El caso que instalé ArchLinux en una partición de 50GB en el disco duro de 1TB, todo iba normal, se instaló correctamente hasta que me pidió reiniciar, reinicia siempre con windows y no veo la forma de hacerlo arrancar con el sistema linux que esta en la partición de mi disco duro.

Probé arrancando desde el disco duro de 1TB desde la bios pero igual me inicia con windows.

Se les agradecería un consejo o solución, Saludos de antemano.

Comment: Debiste instalar OS-prober

Comment: La instalación la has hecho en MBR o UEFI. ¿Qué gestor de arranque has usado? Grub , systemd-boot ¿? ¿Dónde has instalado el gestor de arranque? Si das más datos seguramente alguien te puede ayudar... Saludos.

Comment: Cuando vas a instalar GRUB (si es que es eso lo que usas), debes hacerlo en el disco duro de arranque marcado como boot. Imagino que será el de windows, OJO! una vez hecho esto, el boot de windows no funcionará sin el grub. También tienes que tener en cuenta si es MBR o UEFI, en caso de UEFI hay que hacer varias cosas antes.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que haya sido un error en la instalación de `grub`. Debes instalarlo en el disco, no en la partición (asumo que es `sda`).

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Nota: si no apareciera una vez funcionando la opción de Windows en grub, instala `os prober`:

```
pacman -S os-prober
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 Tiende a borrar sistemas operativos de versiones anteriores de Windows o cualquier otra versión del sistema operativo que no sea de Microsoft, ami me paso algo muy parecido con el ordenador de sobremesa, prueba a desactivar Windows defender y otros servicios en services.msc